# Сделать наследования классов с таким классом

Tags: python

Сделать наследования классов с таким классом

```
class Person:

"""
 material - матеріал
 price -  цена
 color - цвет
 country - країна
 sale -  знижки
 size - розмір
"""
def __init__(self,material,price,color,country,sale,size):#створення змінних
    self.material = material
    self.price = price
    self.color = color
    self.country = country
    self.sale = sale
    self.size = size
    if self.country == "USA":
        self.price += self.price * 0.5


def _self(self,material,price,color,country,sale,size, arr):#створення змінних
    self.material = material
    self.price = price
    self.color = color
    self.country = country
    self.sale = sale

def country_price(self):#створення метода  залежності ціни від країни
    if self.country == "USA":
        self.price += self.price * 0.5

v1=Person("кожа", "22", "red", "44", "54", "47")
v2=Person("льон", "44", "blue", "77", "45", "56")
v3=Person("кожа", "67", "black", "90", "54", "31")
v4=Person("кожа", "99", "whilte", "11", "80", "45")
v5=Person("хлопок", "21", "yellow", "34", "46", "45")
a1=v1.material + " " + v1.price + " " + v1.color +" "+v1.country+" "+v1.sale+" "+v1.size
a2=v2.material + " " + v2.price + " " + v2.color +" "+v2.country+" "+v2.sale+" "+v2.size
a3=v3.material + " " + v3.price + " " + v3.color +" "+v3.country+" "+v3.sale+" "+v3.size
a4=v4.material + " " + v4.price + " " + v4.color +" "+v4.country+" "+v4.sale+" "+v4.size
a5=v5.material + " " + v5.price + " " + v5.color +" "+v5.country+" "+v5.sale+" "+v5.size
print(a1);
print(a2);
print(a3);
print(a4);
print(a5);
```

Comment: А в чём сложности возникли? Опишите проблему детальнее

Comment: мне нужно чтобы класс наследовался

Comment: Ну а проблема то в чём конкретно? Я сейчас проверил - класс великолепно наследуется.

Comment: И, кстати, вы уверены, что класс, который хранит информацию о материале, размере, цене и цвете, должен называться Person?

Comment: да! Создать иерархию классов с использованием механизма наследования. В качестве базового класса должен выступать класс, разработанный Person

Answer (score 0):

Ну раз вы больше никаких уточнений не хотите нам привести, то вот вам решение в полном соответствии с приведённым ТЗ.

Просто допишите этот фрагмент после вашего кода, и у вас будет превосходная иерархия классов с использованием механизма наследования:

```
class PersonSecond(Person):
    pass

class PersonThird(PersonSecond):
    pass

class PersonFourth(PersonThird):
    pass
```

Comment: можно полностю код с мои классом

Comment: Я же написал: просто вставьте этот фрагмент под тот код, который есть у вас.

Comment: Вот больше ТЗ посмотрите
1. В иерархии должно быть не менее двух уровней и не менее четырех классов (вместе с базовым классом).
2. Каждый класс-потомок должен иметь хотя бы один собственный атрибут и хотя бы один метод.
3. В каждом классе-потомке должен быть собственный конструктор.

Comment: Ну так допишите это всё в тот код, который я вам уже привёл. Или вы хотите, чтобы я всё это за вас сделал?

Comment: да пожалуйста если можно. у меня мозг кипит